# how to add headers in websocket

Tags: angular, websocket

I am developing an angular2 application with WebSocket. I want to open Api connection with basic authentication. But WebSocket does not support headers. I don't know how to add my basic authentication with my Api.

```
let websocket = new WebSocket("ws://host:port/api/homepage?v=1");
      this.websocket.onopen =  (evt) => {
          this.websocket.send("Hello World");
};
```

Above code used to open WebSocket connection. Here where I add my basic authentication.

I tried to like this

```
// this.websocket.headers("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
```

But it throws error

> No header method in websocket

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let websocket = new WebSocket("ws://username:password@host.com:port/api/homepage?v=1");
      this.websocket.onopen =  (evt) => {
          this.websocket.send("Hello World");
};
```

Comment: I got this response failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Comment: try putting the ip adresse instead of the hostname, `"ws://username:password@192.168.1.10:port/api/homepage?v=1"`